# Parallel design of program working with Flink and scala

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

This is the context:

1. There is an input event stream,
2. There are some methods to apply on
   the stream, which applies different logic to evaluates each event,
   saying it is a "good" or "bad" event.
3. An event can be a **real** "good" one **only if** it passes all the methods, otherwise it is a "bad" event.
4. There is an output event stream who has result of event and its eventID.

To solve this problem, I have two ideas:

1. We can apply each method sequentially to each event. ***But*** this is a kind of batch processing, and doesn't apply the advantages of stream processing, in the same time, it takes Time(M(ethod)1) + Time(M2) + Time(M3) + ....., which maybe not suitable to real-time processing.
2. We can pass the input stream to each method, and then we can run each method **in parallel**, each method **saves** the bad event into a permanent storage, then the Main method could **query** the permanent storage to get the result of each event. ***But*** this has some problems to solve:

   - how to execute methods in parallel in the programming language(e.g. Scala), how about the performance(network, CPUs, memory)
   - how to solve the synchronization problem? It's sure that those methods need sometime to calculate and save flag into the permanent storage, but the Main just need less time to query the flag， which a delay issue occurs.
   - etc.

This is not a kind of tech and design question, I would like to ask your guys' ideas, if you have some new ideas or ideas to solve the problem ? Looking forward to your opinions.

Comment: Do it sequentially (#1). If time becomes a problem, you can always partition the stream, and parallelize the processing of events.

Comment: @Dima do you have a link for me to understand it?

Comment: Not sure what you want to understand

Answer (score 0):

Parallel streams, each doing the full set of evaluations sequentially, is the more straightforward solution. But if that introduces too much latency, then you can fan out the evaluations to be done in parallel, and then bring the results back together again to make a decision.

To do the fan-out, look at the split operation on DataStream, or use side outputs. But before doing this n-way fan-out, make sure that each event has a unique ID. If necessary, add a field containing a random number to each event to use as the unique ID. Later we will use this unique ID as a key to gather back together all of the partial results for each event.

Once the event stream is split, each copy of the stream can use a MapFunction to compute one of evaluation methods.

Gathering all of these separate evaluations of a given event back together is a bit more complex. One reasonable approach here is to union all of the result streams together, and then key the unioned stream by the unique ID described above. This will bring together all of the individual results for each event. Then you can use a RichFlatMapFunction (using Flink's keyed, managed state) to gather the results for the separate evaluations in one place. Once the full set of evaluations for a given event has arrived at this stateful flatmap operator, it can compute and emit the final result.